# Как отправить на сервер значение button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Как отправить на сервер в POST ещё и значение кнопки button?

```js
$('form input[type="button"]').on('click', function(e){
  $('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first" value="">
  <input type="button" name="second" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: она вроде по-дефолту отправляется если `value` прописан

Comment: Тоже думал, что автоматом отправляет, но нет

Comment: обычно используют `type="submit"` и в таком случае js не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="second" value="Send">
</form>
```

```
$_POST['first']
$_POST['second']
```